# How to save page via Firefox, Chrome, PhantomJS in Java Code

Tags: java, webdriver

I want to save a website like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> in Chrome or FireFox, How can I do it in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Use **HtmlUnit**

`HtmlUnit` is a "`GUI-Less browser for Java programs`". It models HTML documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your "normal" browser.

More [detail](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

And to save the page use below code :

```
public class SavePage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = client.getPage("https://www.google.co.in");

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("d:\\google.html");
        writer.write(page.asXml()); //Save page on file system 
        writer.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: But HTMLunit some time crash is i open a lot of page

Comment: anyway, please tel me how to save page in HTML Unit like "Ctrl + S" in Chrome

Comment: You can go with page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString() in place of asXml but it will not retrieve image and css.I dont think htmlunit provide any method to download everything from page.You have to write method to download image and css